# Angular HTTP DELETE request not working with Django backend

Tags: python, node.js, django, angular

I am facing an issue with performing HTTP DELETE requests from my Angular frontend to my Django backend. The deletion works fine when testing it with Django Postman, but it fails to work when triggered from the Angular interface.
Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
      deleteClick(item: any) {   if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
      const departmentToDelete = {
        DepartmentId: 145742,
        DepartmentName: 'TELECOMM',
        description: 'it is a department to sale'
      };
  
      this.service.deleteDepartment(departmentToDelete).subscribe(
        (data) => {
          alert(data.toString());
          this.refreshDepList();
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log('Error occurred while deleting the department:', error);
          alert('Error occurred while deleting the department.');
        }
      );   } }
```

Backend code (Django):

```
elif request.method == 'DELETE':   department_data =      
JSONParser().parse(request)   department =      
Departments.objects.get(DepartmentId=department_data['DepartmentId'])
department.delete()   return JsonResponse("Deleted Successfully!!",  
safe=False)
```

When triggering the deletion from the Angular interface, I receive the following error in the console

```
rest_framework.exceptions.ParseError: JSON parse error - Expecting
value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) [10/Jul/2023 12:00:02] "DELETE
/department/145742 HTTP/1.1" 500 98390
```

I have verified that the URL and headers are correct, and the request payload seems to be in the expected JSON format. However, I can't figure out why the deletion is not working in the Angular interface.

Any help or guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

here is my models

```
     from django.utils import timezone import uuid from django.db import  
     models
      class Departments(models.Model):
      DepartmentId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
      DepartmentName = models.TextField()
      description = models.TextField()
      date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
      date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  
      def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
          if not self.DepartmentId:
              max_id = Departments.objects.aggregate(models.Max('DepartmentId'))['DepartmentId__max']
              if max_id is not None:
                  self.DepartmentId = (max_id // 13249 + 1) * 13249  # Increment the first 4 digits
              else:
                  self.DepartmentId = 13249  # Starting value if no records exist yet
          super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

here is my views:

```
     from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt from   
     rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser from django.http import   
     JsonResponse from EmployeeApp.models import Departments,Service from 
     EmployeeApp.serializers import DepartmentSerializer,ServiceSerializer
      @csrf_exempt def departmentApi(request, DepartmentId=None):
      if request.method == 'GET':
          departments = Departments.objects.all()
          departments_serializer = DepartmentSerializer(departments, many=True)
          return JsonResponse(departments_serializer.data, safe=False)
  
      elif request.method == 'POST':
          department_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
          department_serializer = DepartmentSerializer(data=department_data)
          if department_serializer.is_valid():
              department_serializer.save()
              return JsonResponse("Added Successfully!!", safe=False)
          return JsonResponse(department_serializer.errors, status=400)
  
      elif request.method=='PUT':
          department_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
          department=Departments.objects.get(DepartmentId=department_data['DepartmentId'])
          department_serializer=DepartmentSerializer(department,data=department_data)
          if department_serializer.is_valid():
              department_serializer.save()
              return JsonResponse("Updated Successfully!!", safe=False)
          return JsonResponse("Failed to Update.", safe=False)
  
  
      elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        department_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        department=Departments.objects.get(DepartmentId=department_data['DepartmentId'])
      department.delete()
      return JsonResponse("Deleted Successfully!!", safe=False)
```

Also it deletion do work in my postman but not angular interface

[image]

here is the get

[image]

but in angular interface it gamme this

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\core\handlers  \exception.py",
line 55, in inner
response = get_response(request)   File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py",
line 197, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py",
line 54, in wrapped_view
return view_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "D:\third year\New folder (4)\New folder\DjangoAPI\EmployeeApp\views.py", line 33, in
departmentApi
department_data = JSONParser().parse(request)   File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\rest_framework\parsers.py",
line 66, in parse
raise ParseError('JSON parse error - %s' % str(exc)) rest_framework.exceptions.ParseError: JSON parse error - Expecting
value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) [10/Jul/2023 12:44:30] "DELETE
/department/[object%20Object] HTTP/1.1" 500 98547

[image]

Comment: Can you post the json that is being sent?

Comment: ive already published the json being sent in postman and it worked 
you cam see the deleteclick code that i sent to get a clear idea of the json being sent

Comment: Ι meant the actual text that angular sends to the backend. The error points to a JSON parsing error, so this is what needs to be investigated.